# Combobox referencing access 2010 query

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a form with a combo box which is linked to a table (TblProduct)which show the product description and is ordered by the product ID

I also have a text box called txtStockValue.

I want users to select the product form the combo box, do a stock count and input the stock value in the txtStockValue box.

There is then a button which confirms the update.

I have the following coding for the button, but I put the problem in this section of the forum because I think my problem is in the query... I have never used combo boxes before

the coding is as follows

```
Private Sub StockOK_Click()
Dim SQLDelete1 As String
Dim SQLDelete2 As String
Dim SQLUpdate As String

SQLDelete1 = "DELETE * FROM TblStock WHERE TblStock.ProductID = CboStockItem.ProductID"
SQLDelete2 = "DELETE * FROM TblTotalSales WHERE TblTotalSales.ProductID = CboStockItem.ProductID"
SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO TblStock (ProductID, StockLevel) SELECT ProductID FROM CboStockItem.ProductID AND SELECT StockLevel FROM TxtStockValue"

If IsNull(Me.TxtStockValue) Then MsgBox "Please Select An Item To Update Stock And Ensure A Value Has Been Entered" Else:
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete1
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete2
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLUpdate

End Sub
```

I tried to reference the combo box as CboStockItem (The name of the combo box) but I don't think I have done this correctly.

The code is basically supposed to delete all the items form 2 tables where the items ID is the same as in the product selected from the combo box and then insert the new value for stock into the stock table.

A secondary point is that before the data is deleted it should be updated into two excel files for storage (a stock Excel file called Stock and a sales Excel file called sales). This I think I can do, but I thought to include it for interest.

Comment: If you find that Joey has solved this problem, you should accept the answer. This is good for Joey, SO, and you :)

Comment: its the final part of my project.  I have two tables, one is called stock and one is called total sales.

I am trying to use this as a stock update so that the previous sales and stock are exported to excel as a store, and also removed from the database.  This is for an Epos system for a pub, so the stock take will be done once a month - once a quarter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string to set your SQL should be like this:

```
SQLDelete1 = "DELETE * FROM TblStock WHERE TblStock.ProductID = " & cboStockItem.value
```

Comment: It is much safer to reference the form, Me is fine in this case, so `& Me.cboStockItem`

Comment: Thanks, but how would I word it in the update query?

    SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO TblStock (ProductID, StockLevel) SELECT ProductID FROM CboStockItem.ProductID AND SELECT StockLevel FROM TxtStockValue"
Would it be 
    SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO TblStock (ProductID, StockLevel) SELECT StockLevel FROM TxtStockValue AND SELECT ProductID FROM " & Me.cboStockItem.value

Comment: `SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO TblStock (ProductID, StockLevel) VALUES ( " & Me.CboStockItem & "," & Me.StockLevel & " )"`

Comment: ... and include `Debug.Print SQLUpdate` after you build that string so that, in case of problems, you can check in the Immediate window to see the exact statement you're asking the db engine to execute.

Comment: Thanks Remou and HansUp for clarifying!

Comment: On a side note, is it possible to export only some of the rows from a table into an excel file? I.E, the rows with the same product ID?

Comment: Yes, it is. Use a query and export that. You can refer to the combobox in the query.